# why laravel does not start server with php

Tags: php, laravel-7

every time I try to start the server through php artisan serve, it gives this error.

I've tried clearing cache, changing laravel's php version and nothing.

This project is in laravel 7.

```
Please provide a valid cache path.

  at C:\Users\paloma\Documents\GitHub Repositories\nova\projeto-leiloes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php:36
    32| */
    33| public function __construct(Filesystem $files, $cachePath)
    34| {
    35| if (! $cachePath) {
  > 36| throw new InvalidArgumentException('Please provide a valid cache path.');
    37| }
    38|
    39| $this->files = $files;
    40| $this->cachePath = $cachePath;

  1 C:\Users\paloma\Documents\GitHub Repositories\nova\projeto-leiloes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider.php:91
      Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler::__construct()

  2 C:\Users\paloma\Documents\GitHub Repositories\nova\projeto-leiloes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:805
      Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::Illuminate\View\{closure}()
```

ps aux | grep 'apache|httpd|nginx'

mkdir -p storage/framework